# c# mvc.net - One or more multiple form action in cshtml?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

[Please see the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3w5n.png)

I have three actions. (Remove the class, Reserve the class and Add more classes)

Can I use one or more multiple form action in cshtml?

Comment: Did you google for this? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: I was about to answer, then I saw this comment from @L-Four :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Comment: In this cshtml, I want to pass hiddenfor object. So, write three times hidden for object?

Comment: Yeah go for it. Might want to look at ways for the controller to determine which action should be executed based on the values submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In order to call them in View:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove Button Name" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { yourParameterHere= 'ValueOfYourParameter' })'" />
```

Basically your ActionName would be the name of your Action = "Remove" for example.

Your Parameter name would be the parameter name that you will be receiving in your ActionName for example:

```
public ActionResult Remove(int intRemoveID) //intRemoveID would be your parametername
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This should be the same on other buttons as well. Let me know if you need clarifications.